# Getting updated global variable in JavaScript - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am getting `undefined` type for:

```
$(".ui-slider-handle").attr("title", '"'+current+'"');
```

As you can see I tried to alert the `current` in line 29 and alerts the correct updated `current` value but it is not functioning on `.attr("title", '"'+current+'"')`. Why is this happening, and how can I solve this issue?

```
 $(function () {
     var current;
     $("#slider-vertical").slider({
         orientation: "vertical",
         range: "min",
         min: 0,
         max: 100,
         value: 60,
         slide: function (event, ui) {
             $("#amount").val(ui.value);
             var offsets = $('.ui-slider-handle').offset();
             var top = offsets.top;
             $(".tooltip").css('top', top - 90 + "px");
             $(".tooltip-inner").text(ui.value);

             function setCurrent() {
                 current = ui.value;
             }
             setCurrent();
         }
     });
     $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));


     $(".ui-slider-handle").attr("rel", "tooltip");
     $(".ui-slider-handle").attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
     $(".ui-slider-handle").attr("data-placement", "left");

     //  alert(current);
     //   $(".ui-slider-handle").attr("title", "50");
     $(".ui-slider-handle").attr("title", '"'+current+'"');

     $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you have the single-double-single quote for?  Try to use:

```
$(".ui-slider-handle").attr("title", current);
```

Does it require double quotes to appear?

I'm gonna leave that cause it was boneheaded and funny.  Anyway, current is inside the scope of the function and does not have a value outside of it.  Try this instead:
Change this:

```
function setCurrent() {
current = ui.value;
}
setCurrent();
```

to

```
current = ui.value;
```

Or you could just return the value like this:

```
function setCurrent() {
return ui.value;
}

current = setCurrent();
```

Comment: Hi cOp, I already tried this .No error message but the tooltip not working either.

Comment: well, doesn't really matter the tool-tip not working! did you see the demo I provide?

Comment: Yeah, I see it.  Did you uncomment the questionable line?  Now the tooltip isn't following the slider properly but the value is there.

Comment: and it shows Undefined when you hover for the fist time

Comment: It shows 'undefined' like that because it really doesn't have a defined value yet.  You declare the variable 'current' as nothing.  If you set a value to it, it remains that until you invoke the 'slider'.  But once you stop, it goes back to the value you set it at because the function hasn't run yet.